# WSO2 APIM:mc.setPayloadJSON throwing org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException

Tags: wso2-api-manager

I am trying to manipulate JSON request in WSO2 APIM using Javascript and sending it as application/json. I have modified axis2.xml & axis2_blocking_client.xml to include JsonStreamFormatter and JsonStreamBuilder as well. While setting mc.setPayloadJSON getting org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException.
Below are the code snippet and error logs:

```
API snippet(carbon.xml):

  <api context="/TestVDB/v1.0" name="creator--testVDB" version="v1.0" version-type="context">
        <resource faultSequence="fault" methods="POST" url-mapping="/VcVDB">
            <inSequence>
                <filter regex="PRODUCTION" source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE">
                    <then>
                        <property action="remove"
                            name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
                        <property expression="json-eval($.)" name="JSONPayload"/>
                        <log level="custom">
                            <property
                                expression="get-property('JSONPayload')" name="requestJson"/>
                        </log>
                        <property name="action" value="SUBMIT"/>
                        <script language="js"><![CDATA[var requestJson=mc.getProperty('JSONPayload');
var requestJsonObject=JSON.parse(requestJson);
var requestJsonString=JSON.stringify(requestJsonObject);
var VDBJsonObj = new Object();
VDBJsonObj.inputJsonReq=requestJsonString;
newResponseJson=JSON.stringify(VDBJsonObj);
print(newResponseJson);
mc.setPayloadJSON(newResponseJson);]]></script>
                        <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2"
                            type="STRING" value="POST"/>
                        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" value="application/json"/>
                        <property
                            expression="get-property('SYSTEM_TIME')" name="api.ut.backendRequestTime"/>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint name="creator--testVDB_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                                <http uri-template="{var.uri.host}.{var.uri.port}/FpuVDB/CallRouterView/json/CallRequestRouter"/>
                            </endpoint>
                        </send>
                    </then>
                    <else>
                        <sequence key="_sandbox_key_error_"/>
                    </else>
                </filter>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <class name="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtResponseHandler"/>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
        </resource>
        <handlers>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.CORSRequestHandler">
                <property name="apiImplementationType" value="ENDPOINT"/>
            </handler>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler">
                <property name="id" value="A"/>
                <property name="policyKeyResource" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/res-tiers.xml"/>
                <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
                <property name="policyKeyApplication" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/app-tiers.xml"/>
            </handler>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler">
                <property name="configKey" value="gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml"/>
            </handler>
            <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
        </handlers>
    </api>
```

**Error Logs:**

```
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,340] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> POST /TestVDB/v1.0/VcVDB HTTP/1.1
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,341] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Host: 10.178.233.87:8245
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,341] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Connection: keep-alive
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,341] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Content-Length: 1885
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,341] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,341] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Cache-Control: no-cache
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,341] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,341] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Content-Type: application/json
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,341] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Authorization: Bearer b51763484717d618473cc9662b237504
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,342] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Postman-Token: 9ac93374-5fc7-3f01-1c2d-c23b4fefdecf
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,342] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Accept: */*
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,342] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,342] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 >> Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,350]  INFO - LogMediator requestJson = {
  "@context": "__http://etc.abc.com/metadata/context.jsonld",
  "@id": "__http://etc.abc.com/message/id/abc/Router/327a3063-ab17-48c5-e053-336edb20aae9",
  "@type": "msg:Message",
  "msg:format": "__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/Formats/MessageFormat-1",
  "msg:type": "__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/MessageTypes/ServiceCall-1",
  "msg:from": "__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/Contributors/abc/pqr",
  "msg:to": "__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/Contributors/abc/VirusCheck",
  "msg:service": {
    "@id": "__http://etc.abc.com/message/id/abc/Router/327a3063-ab18-48c5-e053-336edb20aae9",
    "@type": "msg:ServiceCall",
    "svc:time": "2016-05-10T05:52:05.029Z",
    "svc:type": "__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/ServiceCall/PerformVirusCheck",
    "svc:about": "cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr",
    "svc:resource": [
      "https://s3-ucmdata-pqr.s3.amazonaws.com/EU_WEST_1-cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr-16f817e9f8eb07db4beb70e5d021d13c-63503_58484_99949.pdf?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22EU_WEST_1-cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr-16f817e9f8eb07db4beb70e5d021d13c-63503_58484_99949.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJTIYS75JIN6ZWRSQ&Expires=1473241925&Signature=cKyblhLqxS7KAH6k8Okca5BEjyk%3D"
    ],
    "svc:params": [
      {
        "@context": {
          "virus": "__http://etc.abc.com/data/ns/messages/abc/VirusCheckService-1/"
        },
        "virus:post-result-at": "https://s3-ucmdata-pqr.s3.amazonaws.com/VIRUS_EU_WEST_1-cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr-16f817e9f8eb07db4beb70e5d021d13c-63503_58484_99949.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=FDSJTIYS75JIN6ZWRSQ&Expires=1473241925&Signature=ev44nf8MA4%2Fkfa9IRmonO8ANpMk%3D",
        "virus:remove-file-properties": true,
        "virus:and-again-please": null
      }
    ]
  },
  "@timestamp": "2016-05-10T05:52:05.029Z"
}
{"inputJsonReq":"{\"@context\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/metadata/context.jsonld\",\"@id\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/message/id/abc/Router/327a3063-ab17-48c5-e053-336edb20aae9\",\"@type\":\"msg:Message\",\"msg:format\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/Formats/MessageFormat-1\",\"msg:type\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/MessageTypes/ServiceCall-1\",\"msg:from\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/Contributors/abc/pqr\",\"msg:to\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/Contributors/abc/VirusCheck\",\"msg:service\":{\"@id\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/message/id/abc/Router/327a3063-ab18-48c5-e053-336edb20aae9\",\"@type\":\"msg:ServiceCall\",\"svc:time\":\"2016-05-10T05:52:05.029Z\",\"svc:type\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/data/voc/ServiceCall/PerformVirusCheck\",\"svc:about\":\"cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr\",\"svc:resource\":[\"https://cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr.s3.amazonaws.com/EU_WEST_1-cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr-16f817e9f8eb07db4beb70e5d021d13c-63503_58484_99949.pdf?response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3D%22EU_WEST_1-cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr-16f817e9f8eb07db4beb70e5d021d13c-63503_58484_99949.pdf%22&response-content-type=application%2Fpdf&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJABCS75JIN6ZWRSQ&Expires=1473241925&Signature=cKyblhLqxS7KAH6k8njgf5BEjyk%3D\"],\"svc:params\":[{\"@context\":{\"virus\":\"__http://etc.abc.com/data/ns/messages/abc/VirusCheckService-1/\"},\"virus:post-result-at\":\"https://cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr.s3.amazonaws.com/VIRUS_EU_WEST_1-cert-s3-ucmdata-pqr-16f817eop8b07db4beb70e5d021d13c-63503_58484_99949.pdf?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJTXCV75JIN6ZWRSQ&Expires=1473241925&Signature=ev44nf8MA4%2Fkfa9IRdayO8ANpMk%3D\",\"virus:remove-file-properties\":true,\"virus:and-again-please\":null}]},\"@timestamp\":\"2016-05-10T05:52:05.029Z\"}"}
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,364] ERROR - ScriptMediator The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate
com.sun.phobos.script.util.ExtendedScriptException: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected attribute value (<Unknown Source>#8) in <Unknown Source> at line number 8
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:68)
        at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:92)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediateForInlineScript(ScriptMediator.java:306)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.invokeScript(ScriptMediator.java:245)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMediator.mediate(ScriptMediator.java:213)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.filters.FilterMediator.mediate(FilterMediator.java:166)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:81)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:48)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:155)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:378)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:86)
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:65)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:295)
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:317)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:363)
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:142)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: org.mozilla.javascript.WrappedException: Wrapped java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected attribute value (<Unknown Source>#8)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.Context.throwAsScriptRuntimeEx(Context.java:1754)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:148)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.NativeJavaMethod.call(NativeJavaMethod.java:225)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.optimizer.OptRuntime.call1(OptRuntime.java:32)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__91._c_script_0(<Unknown Source>:8)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__91.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:394)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3091)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__91.call(<Unknown Source>)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.gen._Unknown_Source__91.exec(<Unknown Source>)
        at com.sun.phobos.script.javascript.RhinoCompiledScript.eval(RhinoCompiledScript.java:55)
        ... 24 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected attribute value
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consumeName(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:117)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:131)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:162)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:149)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader.consume(JsonXMLStreamReader.java:132)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.hasNext(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:446)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.base.AbstractXMLStreamReader.next(AbstractXMLStreamReader.java:456)
        at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(StreamReaderDelegate.java:88)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:681)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.buildNext(OMElementImpl.java:653)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMNodeImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMNodeImpl.java:122)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getNextOMSibling(OMElementImpl.java:343)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMChildrenIterator.getNextNode(OMChildrenIterator.java:36)
        at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.traverse.OMAbstractIterator.hasNext(OMAbstractIterator.java:58)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:414)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:421)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.removeIndentations(JsonUtil.java:421)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.newJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:530)
        at org.apache.synapse.commons.json.JsonUtil.newJsonPayload(JsonUtil.java:599)
        at org.apache.synapse.mediators.bsf.ScriptMessageContext.setPayloadJSON(ScriptMessageContext.java:628)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at org.mozilla.javascript.MemberBox.invoke(MemberBox.java:126)
        ... 33 more
[
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,375]  INFO - LogMediator STATUS = Executing default 'fault' sequence, ERROR_CODE = 0, ERROR_MESSAGE = The script engine returned an error executing the inlined js script function mediate
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,384] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,385] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,385] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Access-Control-Allow-Headers: authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,385] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,385] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,386] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Origin: chrome-extension://fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,386] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Postman-Token: 9ac93374-5fc7-3f01-1c2d-c23b4fefdecf
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,386] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,386] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Content-Type: application/xml; charset=UTF-8
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,386] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Cache-Control: no-cache
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,386] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Date: Tue, 10 May 2016 11:49:17 GMT
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,386] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Transfer-Encoding: chunked
[2016-05-10 07:49:17,386] DEBUG - headers http-incoming-6 << Connection: keep-alive
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we call mc.setPayloadJSON(newResponseJson); it tries to build the existing payload in the message context and convert it to XML format before setting the modified payload. The conversion is done by the StAXON library [1].
StAXON considers "@" fields as attributes in XML when it does its conversion. [2] [3]
For Example:
{"node": {"@attribute": "myAttrib"}} is represented as 
With respect to StAXON there are two problems in your payload as you already identified too.

1. It has the following Object with an @ fields; the StAXON library does not support it as we cannot set objects inside an XML attribute.
2. An @ field is defined after defining normal fields of a JSON object ("@timestamp": "2016-05-10T05:52:05.029Z"). StAXON also identifies this as problem. Because, in XML, we do not specify attributes after we started defining its child/text fields.

In order to mitigate this issue, we need to avoid building existing message and transformation into XML. For that we need to set following property to remove the existing payload from the message context before calling mc.setPayloadJSON(newResponseJson);

mc.getEnvelope().getBody().getFirstElement().detach();